# Laravel substarction query not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the difference of two columns by substantiation. But this query gives me an error in '`(daily_attendances.in_time - $time) AS profit`' this part. Without this part query works fine.what can be the issue?

```
$time = "07:15:00";

$transportCounts = DB::table('daily_attendances')
           ->join('emp_personal_details', 'daily_attendances.emp_id', '=', 'emp_personal_details.id')
           ->select('emp_personal_details.code','daily_attendances.in_time','(daily_attendances.in_time - $time) AS profit')
           ->where('daily_attendances.in_time', '>', $time)
           ->where('daily_attendances.date', '=', date("Y-m-d"))
           ->get();
```

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: @FMashiro it says column not found . this is the line that error occurs. '(daily_attendances.in_time - $time) AS profit'

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes here...`'(daily_attendances.in_time - $time) AS profit'`

So in your case you are telling MySQL to select value with column `daily_attendances.in_time` to minus a column named `$time`.

PHP will only interpret variables in double quoted strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code like :

```
$transportCounts = DB::table('daily_attendances')
                ->join('emp_personal_details', 'daily_attendances.emp_id', '=', 'emp_personal_details.id')
                ->select('emp_personal_details.code','daily_attendances.in_time',DB::raw('(daily_attendances.in_time - $time) AS profit'))
                ->where('daily_attendances.in_time', '>', $time)
                ->where('daily_attendances.date', '=', date("Y-m-d"))
                ->get();
```